# php pass string to array() function

Tags: php, function

Is there any way to pass string variable to array() function:

```
$ints = '112233,112234';
$arr = array($ints);

//instead of

$arr = array(112233,112234);
```

I know that there are plenty other ways, but passing the string is my only option:

```
$stArr = array();
foreach($dataTeacherAssWr[0]->getStudents() as $student) {
    $stArr[] = $student->getIdUser();
}
MyCacheManager::clearAssignmentCacheOnHomepageForUsers($_SESSION['id_user'], $stArr);

and the method:

public static function clearAssignmentCacheOnHomepageForUsers($teacherId, $studentId) {
    return self::clearAssignmentCacheOnHomepage(
        Array(
            'teacherIds' => array($teacherId),
            'studentIds' => array($studentId)
        )
    );
}
```

as you can see I can pass $studentId as "flat" ids in string

Comment: `array()` is a [*language construct*](http://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php) not a function, and you might misinterpret it's usage if you look at it as a function.

Comment: You need to be clearer as to why you think passing a string into array() is your only option, and what you hope to achieve.

Comment: $stArr = array();
    foreach($dataTeacherAssWr[0]->getStudents() as $student) {
        $stArr[] = $student->getIdUser();
    }
    MyCacheManager::clearAssignmentCacheOnHomepageForUsers($_SESSION['id_user'], $stArr);
 
    public static function clearAssignmentCacheOnHomepageForUsers($teacherId, $studentId) {
        return self::clearAssignmentCacheOnHomepage(
            Array(
                'teacherIds' => array($teacherId),
                'studentIds' => array($studentId)
            )
        );
    }

Comment: I guess $teacherId and $studentId are strings formatted like "112233,112234" ? Literally all you need to do is replace `'teacherIds' => array($teacherId);` with `'teacherIds' => explode(',',$teacherId);` and the same for `'studentIds' => ...` ... so you **don't** have to use `array();`

Answer (score 3):

Try using the explode function to split the numbers separated by commas into an array...

```
explode(',', $ints);
```

With your example...

```
$ints = '112233,112234';
$arr = explode(',', $ints);
```

Produces the following output:

```
Array ( [0] => 112233 [1] => 112234 )
```

---

If you are looking to pass a string to the language construct array(), it simply cannot be done. You can give it a comma separated list for example `array(112233, 112234);` but you cannot give it `array("112233,112234");` The [array() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) will explain what syntax it will accept.

It will not know that the comma separates a list of integers and that you want it split. All it cares is that you've given it a string, so it will create an array with a string in it. It's not a mind-reader, so you need to separate the values yourself.

Comment: as I mentioned - I need to pass the string to language construct

Comment: Why do you need to? You can't pass a string to the language construct. Check the docs for the syntax it will accept: http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php . What exactly is stopping you from using explode instead? It produces exactly the same response.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)**

```
$array = explode(",", $string);
```

---

**Input:**

```
$string = '112233,112234';
$array = explode(",", $string);
var_dump($array);
```

**Output:**

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "112233" [1]=> string(6) "112234" }
```

Comment: please, read the question! language construct array() is my only option

Comment: @Wojciechk That isn't possible. Array will take a `comma separated list`, won't take a string and separate it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you must have your data in a comma-separated string, you can simply [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it on the comma to get the array:

```
$ints = '112233,112234';
$arr = explode(',', $ints);
```

Comment: please, read the question! language construct array() is my only option

Comment: @Wojciechk language construct `array()` has a specific syntax.  You cannot require to use one construct with a syntax from another.  If you cannot use `explode` but do require a CSV string, then you simply cannot achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way:

```
    $separator=",";
    $str="112233,112234,112235,112236,112237";
    $arr = explode($separator, $str);
    //print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting existing, correct answers instead of posting your own, similar one that doesn't seem to bring anything new to the table. =)